# How do `Hash#reject!` and `Hash#reject` differ from `Hash#delete_if`?

Tags: ruby

How do `reject!` and `reject` differ from `delete_if` for a `Hash` in Ruby? Can anyone explain the differences between them with simple code snippets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the other answers are referring to `Array#delete_if` and not `Hash#delete_if`, which seems to be what you are asking, I thought I should clarify.

As others have pointed out, `reject` and `reject!` differ in that `reject!` version modifies the hash in-place, while `reject` creates a new hash. Meanwhile `delete_if` is *almost* the same as `reject!`.

In fact, for an `Array`, `reject!` and `delete_if` are *exactly* the same.

However, for a `Hash`, they are slightly different. `reject!` returns `nil` if no changes were made, or the hash if changes were made. `delete_if` always returns the hash.

```
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

return_value = hash.delete_if {|k, v| v > 100}
# hash is unchanged, return_value is {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

return_value = hash.reject! {|k, v| v > 100}
# hash is unchanged, return_value is nil
```

So if you wanted to check whether changes were made to the hash after deleting the elements, you could use `reject!` and check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the docs it tells you that reject! is "Equivalent to Array#delete_if"

reject and reject! differ in that the bang (reject!) causes the changes to happen directly on the array you're working with, whereas reject will leave the array you're working with untouched, but will return a new array.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
b = a.reject {|x| x >= "b" }   #=> a is untouched, but b is ["a"]
a.reject! {|x| x >= "b" }   #=> a is now modified and is ["a"]
```

Comment: any difference `reject!` and `delete_if`at core ?

Comment: Did you read my first sentence that came straight from the docs?

Comment: so if they are same, why duplicate function they made up. That's why I asked. If any specific areas there where we are bound to use `reject!` not `delete_if` and vice-versa!

Comment: @RubyTheBang Because they were-there doesn't have to be a great reason. Use whichever one reads better in the context of your code.

Comment: This isn't actually quite right! `Hash#delete_if` and `Hash#reject!` are subtly different. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14308082/725792).

Comment: I swear there's a ruby bug with this as well, sometimes delete_if doesn't actually modify the source array.  I get around it with arr = arr.delete_if {|a| a==b}

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could read this from the docs:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject-21 :

> Equivalent to Array#delete_if, deleting elements from self for which the block evaluates to true, but returns nil if no changes were made. The array is changed instantly every time the block is called and not after the iteration is over. See also Enumerable#reject and Array#delete_if.
>   If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject:

> Returns a new array containing the items in self for which the block is not true. See also Array#delete_if
>   If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.